# php codeigniter - managing values in multi select box

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter

I am working on a multibox as a part of my codeigniter based project, here I am trying to move the values across the boxes using custom js code shared below

[image]

The values shown in first box are fetched from db when page loads and used to move the required values to second box using javascript. My goal it that the values already moved to second box should not be visible in the first box after saving the data and at the same time source data for the first box should not be altered.

Right now I am able to select the values to second box and save successfully but when I load the page again after saving I am seeing the moved values in the fist box and this is visually creating duplication of values and would confuse the user. On the other hand if I try to move back the values to the first box which is creating a conflict while saving the data.

Is there any way I could change my code so that moved values will not be available in the first box again

HTML version of multibox

```html
<fieldset class="emp_contact">
  <legend>Area Allocation</legend>
  <div class="form-group input-group">
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10" style="border:1px solid #ccc">
      <tr>
        <td width="40%">
          <p>Available Areas</p>
        </td>
        <td width="12%">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="40%">
          <p>Selected&nbsp; Areas</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td valign="top" id="myarea_list">
          <?php echo $aval_area_list ?>
        </td>
        <select name="aval_id_temp" id="aval_id_temp" multiple style="display:none"></select>
        <td>
          <table width="100%" border="0">
            <tr>
              <td align="center">
                <input type="Button" value=">>" onClick="SelectMoveRows_all(document.form.avail_area, document.form.selec_area)">
                <br>
                <br />
                <input type="Button" value=">" onClick="SelectMoveRows(document.form.avail_area, document.form.selec_area)">
                <br>
                <br>
                <input type="Button" value="<<" onClick="SelectMoveRows_all(document.form.selec_area, document.form.avail_area)">
                <br>

                <br>
                <input type="Button" value="<" onClick="SelectMoveRows(document.form.selec_area, document.form.avail_area)">

              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
        <td valign="top">
          <?php echo $sel_area_list ?>
          <select name="sel_id_temp" id="sel_id_temp" multiple style="display:none"></select>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Javascript functions used

```js
    function SelectMoveRows_all(SS1, SS2) {
      var SelID = '';
      var SelText = '';
      // Move rows from SS1 to SS2 from bottom to top
      for (i = SS1.options.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        //if (SS1.options[i].selected == true)
        {
          SelID = SS1.options[i].value;
          SelText = SS1.options[i].text;
          var newRow = new Option(SelText, SelID);
          SS2.options[SS2.length] = newRow;
          SS1.options[i] = null;
          for (j = SS2.options.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            SS2.options[j].selected = true;
          }
        }
      }
      SelectSort(SS2);
    }

    function SelectMoveRows(SS1, SS2) {
      var SelID = '';
      var SelText = '';
      // Move rows from SS1 to SS2 from bottom to top
      for (i = SS1.options.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (SS1.options[i].selected == true) {
          SelID = SS1.options[i].value;
          SelText = SS1.options[i].text;
          var newRow = new Option(SelText, SelID);
          SS2.options[SS2.length] = newRow;
          SS1.options[i] = null;
          for (j = SS2.options.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            SS2.options[j].selected = true;
          }

        }
      }
      SelectSort(SS2);
    }

    function SelectSort(SelList) {
      var ID = '';
      var Text = '';
      for (x = 0; x < SelList.length - 1; x++) {
        for (y = x + 1; y < SelList.length; y++) {
          if (SelList[x].text > SelList[y].text) {
            // Swap rows
            ID = SelList[x].value;
            Text = SelList[x].text;
            SelList[x].value = SelList[y].value;
            SelList[x].text = SelList[y].text;
            SelList[y].value = ID;
            SelList[y].text = Text;
          }
        }
      }
    }
```